# Parsing strings representing lists of integers and integer spans

Tags: elisp

I am looking for a function that parses integer lists in Emacs Lisp, along the lines of Perl's [Set::IntSpan](http://search.cpan.org/~swmcd/Set-IntSpan-1.16/IntSpan.pm).  I.e., I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
(parse-integer-list "1-3, 4, 8, 18-21")
⇒ (1 2 3 4 8 18 19 20 21)
```

Is there an elisp library somewhere for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
(defun parse-integer-list (str)
  "Parse string representing a range of integers into a list of integers."
  (let (start ranges)
    (while (string-match "\\([0-9]+\\)\\(?:-\\([0-9]+\\)\\)?" str start)
      (push
       (apply 'number-sequence
              (seq-map 'string-to-int
                       (seq-filter
                        'identity
                        (list (match-string 1 str) (match-string 2 str)))))
            ranges)
        (setq start (match-end 0)))
    (nreverse (seq-mapcat 'nreverse ranges))))
```

The code loops over the incoming string searching for plain numbers or ranges of numbers. On each match it calls `number-sequence` with either just a number for a plain match or two numbers for a range match and pushes each resulting number sequence into a list. To account for `push` building the result backwards, at the end it reverses all ranges in the list, concatenates them, then reverses the result and returns it.

Calling `parse-integer-list` with your example input:

```
(parse-integer-list "1-3, 4, 8, 18-21")
```

produces:

```
(1 2 3 4 8 18 19 20 21)
```